# "com/index.php" without slash in apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualhost, website, 301-redirect

Finally I have finished install SSL Certificate and finish to config the redirect from my old site to my new one, but right now when I try to entering from the old site, it send to me to new sit but withouth "/" like:

```
https://newsite.comindex.php?blabla
```

This is my httpd.conf configuration:

```
<VirtualHost oldsite.com:80>
        ServerName oldsite.com
        Redirect permanent "/" https://newsite.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost oldsite:443>
        ServerName oldsite.com
        Redirect permanent "/" https://newsite.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName https://newsite.com
        Redirect permanent "/" https://newsite.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName oldsite.com
        Redirect permanent / https://newsite.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName oldsite.com
        Redirect permanent / https://newsite.com/
        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile oldcert…
        SSLCertificateKeyFile oldkey…
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName https://newsite.com
        Redirect permanent / https://newsite.com/
        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile newcert…
        SSLCertificateKeyFile newkey…

        <Directory /var/www/html/mysite/>

        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

NameVirtualHosts should not be used anymore. Take care that you have a trailing slash in your Directory directive.